# How to crop the signature from a box in a pdf with imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I need to extract the box with a hand-written signature from a scanned document.

My PDF looks like this: [Link to Dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1117936/mock.pdf)

People will download this, sign it, then upload it back to me. How can I extract the insides of that signature box? (I can modify PDF if needed, add some borders, barcodes, whatever would help.)

I've tried all sorts of imagemagick things. I can get estimated coordinates, something like this:

```
convert -crop 350x75+180+300 mock.pdf mock.png
```

It gets me close, but not precise(people scan differently). But now I have this extracted signature:

[image]

Now I still don't know how to get into the box and crop only that part. I have tried with some trim and fuzz and even multicrop, but no real results.

Some examples of what I've tried:

```
convert -fuzz 10% -bordercolor black -border 2x2 -trim +repage

convert -trim

convert -trim +repage

multicrop -f 10% -b black -border 1x1 -trim + repage

multicrop -f 10% -b white -border 1x1 -trim + repage
```

I only got to trim white around my border, but not up to a pixel.

I even tried using tesseract to find the words SIGN HERE, and extract coordinates, and approximate the coordinates from that - but I'm still stuck with the same problem, how to only get the inside of the box.

What else can I try?

I can pipe multiple convert commands in a shell file, no problem there. The background (probably similar to white, depends on the scanning) can be extracted, no problem - in fact, that's the desired efect, to make it transparent in the end, but didn't want to make this a part of the question if it is going to complicate things.

Any examples of what I can try are highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want exactly.  I think you know the box coordinates, why not crop just inside the black box outline.  Perhaps convert -crop 355x78+175+290 mock.pdf mock.png

Comment: @Paul thanks, but I don't know the **exact** coordinates of the box. I do on the original form - but people will print it out, then sign it, then scan the signed form. When they scan, they might move the scan a bit here or there and skew the box from my original coordinates. So I only know approximate cooridnates of the box.

Comment: Getting a completely 100% accurate with no errors might be challenging.  How much worst case analysis must we assume?  What if the user draw another box inside your box to try to trick your program?  Can the user do this?  What if the user draw a big signature that goes outside the box?  What if the user rotates the piece of paper into the scanner at a 45 degree angle?  In this case even the crop trick above will not work to get the approximate region.

Comment: Well, reasonable will do, not exact. If you can help me get a convert command that will just get to within the box with a milimeter or two from the border, that's fine. If the user rotates the sig, I can live with that, tell the user he'll need to scan again. If the user tries to do some trickery, that's also no problem, this thing goes to human operator in the end anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the actual black box around it, this may be a duplicate of [How can I detect boxes in an image and pull them out as individual files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074860/how-can-i-detect-boxes-in-an-image-and-pull-them-out-as-individual-files)

Comment: I do have the box around it. I did try with that approach, but I also have the other two boxes (from the PDF) that seem to be confusing my algorithm, so I can't extract the exact coords.

Comment: if you have a rough idea of the box you are looking for, can you crop down to that quarter or so of the page, then try to algo?

Comment: That is what I'm doing right now, approximately crop from within the box. But I might try that - expand the search to just look at the lower right quarter and then find my box. Anyway, this is a relatively good answer, and here is the bounty :) Before it expires and goes to nobody at all.